# creating a file inside of a specific directory using terminal

Tags: linux, github, terminal, directory-structure

in terminal is it possible to create a file in a spesific directory without being inside of that folder? for example: 
1)create a folder names RESOURCES in the working directory
 terminal: touch resources
2)now create a file style.css inside of resources folder
 2.1. cd resources 
 2.2 ls
 2.3 touch style.css
is there way to skip some of the steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just:

```
$ mkdir resources
$ touch resources/style.css
```